# What's effect of introducing infinitely high denomination bank notes during hyperinflation?

Tags: inflation

Countries that suffer from hyperinflation often print banknotes with many zeroes.

Recently I had a showerthought: Let's imagine a government suffering from hyperinflation go crazy and begin begin printing money with [Googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex) denomination for example.
That's a so large number that if we would turn all atoms in the universe into paper and ink it would be still too few to write it down.

Or they simply print an infinitely high denomination "omega" bill: omega is the symbol used to denote the "infinitary" in the [hyperreal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) number plane, which is larger than any real number.

What are the consequences of such an infinite banknote entering the circulation? Would that country in question be able to buy the entire world before the market can react?

Comment: All of your prior question on this SE have been answered, some over a year ago. Please consider accepting some answers.

Comment: A side note: On most other SE sites you get a lot of answers but seem to accept very few as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems analogous to "if I think the word infinity, does my head explode?" The answer is no. Infinity is an abstraction. You do not have to accept a piece of paper promising infinity. I would even hesitate to accept an incredibly large finite bill.

On tricky countries buying the world: 
You do not buy foreign things in your own currency, first you purchase foreign currency with your currency and then you buy the foreign goods with foreign currency. Printing excessive amounts of money is not only inflationary, it also deteriorates the exchange rate of your currency to other currencies. The most your currency has to offer is being able to buy everything in your country. The total value of your currency cannot exceed this. Hence others are unlikely to trade more (e.g. the world) for it.